# Android ExpandableList Header with spinner

Tags: android, expandablelistview, android-spinner

I'm developing an application and I am facing a problem using ExpandableListView. What I'm trying to do is, in `GroupHeader`, not only show the group name, but also an spinner with options. That's because I want to show the football second division games in the list but, also, give the option to choose the round, in case the user wants to check older/future games. SO far I have that 
[image]

As you can see both, title and spinner, shows. Also you can see the arrow on the right which is supposed to expand the list. Problem is that, if I click, only spinner opens, group expand button doesn't. So, here is my question, how can I make both of them work depending on where you click (one or another)??? Is that possible? 
Also I must say that if I only place the `TextView` with the group name works perfect. If I only place the spinner, the problem persists. So I'm guessing that's a focus problem.

Btw: grey areas are the layout backgrounds, so no, they are not hiding behind the button.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, I just neede to add this line     android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" to the Main Layout of the xml where I define the GroupHeader elements.